# Floating a canvas next to a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this placement, where the canvas is floating to the right of a paragraph:

[image]

I've been following similar settings that work for floating images, but I'm not having much luck with canvases.

Here's what I've tried:

**CSS**

```
.container
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.container p
{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}
.container canvas
{
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    border:0.2vw solid blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <canvas>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another div and set width to 50% for float right the canavs or set the canvas float:left , container p width: 25%; with padding right for adjust your space

```css
.container
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.container p
{
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.container canvas
{
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    border:0.2vw solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
    <canvas>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp
All you need to do is change the % from 50 to how much you want and add your content under the column divs